# Number values with leading zeros (09) print as "0"... why?

Tags: php

Here is the PHP block:

```
<?php    
    print 09;        
?>
```

Result:

```
0
```

why is the result 0 instead of 09 or 9 or 0x9 or anything else?

Comment: how about some quotes

Comment: @Dagon why would quotes be required?

Comment: From the docs print() expects a string.

Answer (score 4):

A leading zero indicates octal values. So, `01` is 1 in octal, which is equally 1 in decimal. `010` is 10 in octal, which is 8 in decimal. `09` is not a valid octal number, since there is no digit 9 in the octal system (just 0-7), so PHP silently ignores your error and gives you a zero.

In fact, PHP ignores everything after an invalid digit in octal numbers: `01493` == `014` == `12`. Funnily enough, it does not ignore invalid hex digits: `0xfgf` is an error.

Various languages have different ideas on what they should do in this case. JavaScript, for example, would ignore the octal hint: `010` is 8, but `09` is 9.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question of "why"

Comment: so its not returning "0" as fail?

Comment: @Dagon according to the [php documentation](http://php.net/print) `Returns 1, always.`

Comment: must get around to doing that compSci degree :-)

Comment: @Dagon: No, `echo print(09)` prints `01`, where `0` is the `print(09)` with `9` ignored as above, and `1` is printed by `echo` as `print`'s return value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes so `print` can treat it as `String` instead of an `Integer`.

Try:

```
print "09";
```

or

```
echo "09";
```

Comment: @Dagon  it's just an habit, noted! tks for pointing that.